# How to iterate a string that is concatenate with Select statement of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, loops, string-concatenation

this is my code:

```
SELECT 'Fields 1: ' + COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_Name = 'SystemDefined' and table_schema = 'schemaAsset'
```

and the output is:

```
Fields 1: Asset_No
Fields 1: AssetCategory
Fields 1: AssetClassification
Fields 1: PurchaseType
Fields 1: Department
Fields 1: RespPerson
Fields 1: Status
Fields 1: Location
```

I want the string to iterate so that the output will be:

```
Fields 1: Asset_No
Fields 2: AssetCategory
Fields 3: AssetClassification
Fields 4: PurchaseType
Fields 5: Department
Fields 6: RespPerson
Fields 7: Status
Fields 8: Location
```

what algorithm can i use for this output to be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL-Server 2005+ you can do it using function [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT 'Fields '+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name) AS varchar(5))+': ' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_Name = 'SystemDefined' and table_schema = 'schemaAsset'
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```